# What are the Differences/Similarities between SAML 2.0 and OpenID Connect?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, openid-connect

In the context of SSO What are the Differences/Similarities between SAML 2.0 and OpenID Connect? when would one be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAML:

- Separate protocols for SSO and API security
- Heavy XML payload with expensive processing
- Complex; hinders interoperability
- Enterprise oriented
- Manual trust bootstrapping & certificate management

OpenID Connect:

- SSO for web, mobile and API security in one
- Lightweight REST/JSON
- Simple, developer friendly
- Applies to Enterprise & Consumer domain
- Auto client registration and key management

Consider OpenID Connect to be a more modern version of SAML with extended capabilities. Advanced features of the SAML specs that seem to be missing in the OpenID Connect specs we're practically not deployed or not interoperable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the answer to `when would one be used instead of the other?` is don't use SAML 2.0, use OpenId Connect?

Comment: if your partner uses SAML, use SAML; if your partner supports OpenID Connect use OpenID Connect; currently SAML is more widely adopted in the enterprise domain; that will be the case for the short term

Comment: i don't understand what you mean by `partner` here. I'm trying to implement SSO for two web application both which I control and I'm using the Open Source product keycloak to do that. Would OpenID Connect be a better choice for that based on the benefits you have mentioned in your answer?

Comment: since you're the RP, that means your partner is the OP/IDP; if you control both ends, so it is about intra-enterprise SSO then I'd suggest OpenID Connect as more future safe and easier to develop